# How to do console input like in the "top" linux command?

Tags: c++, c, linux, input, console

So, the linux `top` command has the real time-like loop with console output (nothing fancy), but it uses non-blocking console input which doesn't display typed character in the command line. How it's done? Is there any library for it, do they use threads? I need to write an linux app with the same style (used via ssh) and I have no idea how to do that input (cin in separate thread isn't the solution, `top` uses something other).

Comment: How did you solve it?  If an answer helped you, accept it.  If you found something on your own, you can post an answer yourself.  This way, if people have the same (or similar) questions in the future your question could be of great help.

Comment: @Chad: there wasn't an answer when the comment about problem being solved was posted. I first posted a comment which I replaced with an answer afterwards.

Comment: @Chad: And it is more social, because the OP expected us to invest time for him, of course for free, but himself seems uninterested to help future visitors.

Comment: There wasn't an answer when I posted the comment. The problem was solved because thanks to the comment I know which library is it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to use an implementation of [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

*I don't know how `top` does it.*

Comment: Well: `ldd /usr/bin/top` shows `libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5`. So `top` uses ncurses.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, not using curses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
//#include <sys/ioctl.h>
//#include <sys/time.h>
//#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getkey() returns the next char in the stdin buffer if available, otherwise
//          it returns -1 immediately.
//
int getkey(void)
{
    char ch;
    int error;
    struct termios oldAttr, newAttr;
    int oldFlags, newFlags;
    struct timeval tv;
    int fd = fileno(stdin);
    tcgetattr(fd, &oldAttr);
    newAttr = oldAttr;
    oldFlags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);

    newAttr.c_iflag = 0; /* input mode */
    newAttr.c_oflag = 0; /* output mode */
    newAttr.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* line settings */
    newAttr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; /* minimum chars to wait for */
    newAttr.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; /* minimum wait time */

    // Set stdin to nonblocking, noncanonical input
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    error=tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newAttr);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 10000; // small 0.01 msec delay
    select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (error == 0)
        error=(read(fd, &ch, 1) != 1); // get char from stdin

    // Restore original settings
    error |= tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldAttr);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, oldFlags);

    return (error ? -1 : (int) ch);
}

int main()
{
    int c,n=0;
    printf("Hello, world!\nPress any key to exit. I'll wait for 4 keypresses.\n\n");
    while (n<4)
    {
        //printf("."); // uncomment this to print a dot on each loop iteration
        c = getkey();
        if (c >= 0)
        {
            printf("You pressed '%c'\n", c);
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry that I can't take full credit for this, as I pulled it off the 'net many years back.  I think I've tweaked it a little, but it's mostly unchanged from where I got it.  Unfortunately I didn't add a comment indicating where I found it.

Comment: That looks nice. Does it require some libs to compile or just standard library?

Comment: @user1873947 - No special libs, just the C standard lib & CRT.  I added the #includes at the top of my file in my answer, and commented-out ones that I don't think the function itself actually needs, but left them there in case I was wrong.

Comment: @user1873947 - I dunno... It works for me on CentOS 5.8 using GCC 4.7.2.  I'm pretty sure I ported this as-is from a Solaris box I previously used, but that would have been three years ago.  It's not too difficult to write a simple main() to test this.

Comment: @user1873947 - sample main() added to the post above.

Comment: It's not portable :/ It indeed does work on unixes, but on windows - fatal error: termios.h: No such file or directory|

Comment: @user1873947 - Sorry; I wouldn't have expected it to work on Windows in the first place.  Your question mentions "linux" in both the title and the tags, so I figured a solution that worked on Linux would suffice.

Comment: It works, but the characters still get echoed to the console. Any flags to disable echoing?

Comment: @Spidey - I think you could use `newAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);` instead of `newAttr.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;`, but you'd have to change the whole strategy of the `getkey()` function, which (as written) saves & unconditionally restores the stdin terminal mode, which would turn echo back on before returning. This link shows how you might ask for a password (without echo) and without using curses/ncurses: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=da285de869a78cf3e28b7196c6457fc3&p=1516255&postcount=4